# Jquery multiple file upload issue in Mvc 5 and entity framework 6

Tags: c#, jquery, asp.net, asp.net-mvc, entity-framework

Im having trouble with uploading multiple.
i want to store the path of file into db using ef6
if i upload a single file it works just fiine but when i try to upload multiple files using jquery file upload:
the files are sent but are not saved into database (the are added to context)
but savechanges is called for first file only.
it some times throws

```
(sql connection dose not support multiple transactions)
```

and some times it dosnt. ?!? (strange)
here is my upload action:

```
    [HttpPost]
    public ActionResult Upload(HttpPostedFileBase file)
    {
        try
        {
            Video video = _repository.Upload<Video>(Request.Files[0]);
            video.CategoryId = int.Parse(Request.Form["CategoryId"]);
            int result = _unitOfWork.Commit();
            return Json(new
            {
                Success = result > 0,
                Message = "Successfully uploaded..."
            });
        }
        catch (Exception ex)
        {
            return Json(new
            {
                Success = false,
                Message = ex.Message
            });
        }
    }
```

and here is my upload method:

```
public static T Upload<T>(this IRepository<T> repository, HttpPostedFileBase file)
        where T : DomainEntities.File, IEntity, new()
    {
        const string photoPath = "~/Uploads/Photos/";
        const string audioPath = "~/Uploads/Audios/";
        const string videoPath = "~/Uploads/Videos/";

        Type type = typeof(T);

        T t = new T()
        {
            Date = DateTime.Now,
            Name = file.FileName,
            Size = file.ContentLength.ToString(),
            ContentType = file.ContentType
        };

        if (type == typeof(Photo))
        {
            t.Path = Path.Combine(photoPath, file.FileName);
        }
        else if (type == typeof(Video))
        {
            t.Path = Path.Combine(videoPath, file.FileName);
        }
        else if (type == typeof(Audio))
        {
            t.Path = Path.Combine(audioPath, file.FileName);
        }

        file.SaveAs(HttpContext.Current.Server.MapPath(t.Path));
        repository.Add(t);
         //some times its written correctly equal to number of files but some times not.
        Debug.WriteLine("Added"); 
        return t;
    }
```

Update:
  the files are correctly saveing into specified file system path btw.

and this is the view:

```
<div class="portlet-body form">
    <form id="fileupload" class="form-horizontal" action="/Files/Video/Upload" method="POST" enctype="multipart/form-data">
        <!-- The fileupload-buttonbar contains buttons to add/delete files and start/cancel the upload -->
        <div class="row fileupload-buttonbar">

            <div class="col-lg-7">
                <!-- The fileinput-button span is used to style the file input field as button -->
                <span class="btn green fileinput-button">
                    <i class="fa fa-plus"></i>
                    <span>
                         select
                    </span>
                    <input type="file" name="files[]" multiple>
                </span>
                <button type="submit" class="btn blue start">
                    <i class="fa fa-upload"></i>
                    <span>
                        Upload
                    </span>
                </button>
                <button type="reset" class="btn yellow cancel">
                    <i class="fa fa-ban"></i>
                    <span>
                        cancel
                    </span>
                </button>
                <input type="checkbox" class="toggle">
                <!-- The loading indicator is shown during file processing -->
                <span class="fileupload-loading">
                </span>
            </div>
            <!-- The global progress information -->
            <div class="col-lg-5 fileupload-progress fade">
                <!-- The global progress bar -->
                <div class="progress progress-striped active" role="progressbar" aria-valuemin="0" aria-valuemax="100">
                    <div class="progress-bar progress-bar-success" style="width:0%;">
                    </div>
                </div>
                <!-- The extended global progress information -->
                <div class="progress-extended">
                    &nbsp;
                </div>
            </div>
        </div>
        <!-- The table listing the files available for upload/download -->
        <table role="presentation" class="table table-striped clearfix">
            <tbody class="files"></tbody>
        </table>
    </form>

</div>
```

thanks for help.

Answer (score 0):

I think, you have 2 options, I'm confident that the second one is the best:

Try to work with the request object

```
foreach (string file in Request.Files)
{
    //use the Request.Files[file]
}
```

Or you can redefine the `input` name int his way

```
<input type="file" name="files" value="" multiple="multiple"/>
```

without the array definition, and you can try refactoring your action in this way

```
public ActionResult Upload(HttpPostedFileBase[] files)
    foreach (var file in files) {
        if (file.ContentLength > 0) {
            // Save your file
        }
    }
}
```

It should work.

Comment: the IEnumerable<HttpPostedFileBase> is null when the action is hit. i have to read directly form Request.Files.

Comment: Can you add the portion of view used for calling the action to the question?